# I'm trying to change the spelling dictionary of Texmaker, but I can't find the directory where the dictionaries are stored

Tags: 17.04, latex, texlive

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. I'm trying to change the spelling check from English to Spanish. Apparently the dictionary that Texmaker is currently using is stored in

`/usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB.dic`

but myspell is no where to be found. How can I change the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

my friend, before anything else I warn you that I am new to all this, so I do not understand everything ... but I had exactly the same problem as you and I was able to solve it!

What I did was use Synaptic, and download the myspell-es package.
  After that the myspell-es package appears as installed (in green) in Synaptic.
 Then I right click on the package, and opened properties, there several tabs and I went to the tab "installed files", Here are the directories where the files were installed, for example: "/usr/share/hunspell/es_AR.dic" (Which was the one I used for texmaker and it worked!)

I hope to have been understandable, lucky!